# launch file if button is pressed

Tags: vbscript

I have been playing around with the script below:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

intButton = WshShell.Popup ("5 + 5 = 10  yes or no?  if you answer correctly you win a prize!.",5, , 3 + 48)

select case intButton
  case -1
    strMessage = "You did not click any button within the 5 seconds allotted."
  case 6
    strMessage = "click ok to receive your prize!."
  case 7
    strMessage = "wrong no prize!."
  case 2
    strMessage = "ok see ya!."
end select

WshShell.Popup strMessage, , , 64
```

I would like it to launch a .gif file where it says (click ok to receive your prize). I've tried typing `Wshshell.run "22.gif"` underneath (click ok to receive your prize) but it launches the click ok box and the GIF at the same time.

How can I make it launch the .gif only when they click "OK"?

Comment: don't know how to format text

Comment: Basically select your code and press Ctrl-K (or click on the `{}` button above the edit box).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type,

```
strMessage = "click ok to receive your prize!."
Wshshell.run "22.gif"
```

You are just setting `strMessage` variable to hold the string, and displaying the gif on the line just underneath.

It is the last line of code which actually displays the Popup message.

```
WshShell.Popup strMessage, , , 64
```

A quick work around is to display popup within each case, as following.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

intButton = WshShell.Popup ("5 + 5 = 10  yes or no?  if you answer correctly you win a prize!.",5, , 3 + 48)

select case intButton
  case -1
    strMessage = "You did not click any button within the 5 seconds allotted."
    WshShell.Popup strMessage, , , 64
  case 6
    strMessage =  "click ok to receive your prize!."
    WshShell.Popup strMessage, , , 64
    Wshshell.run "22.gif"
  case 7
    strMessage = "wrong no prize!."
    WshShell.Popup strMessage, , , 64
  case 2
    strMessage = "ok see ya!."
    WshShell.Popup strMessage, , , 64
end select
```

Not directly related to your question, you can directly embed an Internet Explorer frame into your code to gain full control on how to display the gif image,

Replace,

```
Wshshell.run "22.gif"
```

with following and adjust the path,

```
Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        With objExplorer
        .Navigate "about:blank"
        .Visible = 1
        .Document.Title = "Show Image"
        .Toolbar=False
        .Statusbar=False
        .Top=400
        .Left=400
        .Height=400
        .Width=400
        .Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<img src='C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\22.gif'>"
        End With
```

Comment: tnx Abdullah ! for answering my question